# Writing byte arrays back to their original state on disk in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux

This might seem useless to most, but I'm trying to figure out how to write a byte array back to the original file it once was, rather than executing in memory (found an overwhelming amount of information on executing in memory).
Particularly, how to do this in C on linux.

I have converted the linux program 'touch' to a byte array:

```
    char touch[] = {
    0x7F,0x45,0x4C,0x46,0x02,0x01,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x3E,0x00,
    0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xA0,0x38,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x68,0x64,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x40,0x00,0x38,0x00,0x09,0x00,0x40,0x00,
    0x1E,0x00,0x1D,0x00,0x06,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x00,
etc..
```

so I am basically just trying to write touch to the current directory as newtouch.

With windows I found the CreateFile function. Is open() the equivalent on linux?

Any help would be great. thanks

Comment: You know `fopen()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just write your array using `fwrite`, opening the file as binary (no issue on Linux, but text/default mode creates corrupt binary files on Windows because of endline conversion)

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char touch[] = {
    0x7F,0x45,0x4C,0x46,0x02,0x01,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x3E,0x00,
    0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xA0,0x38,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};

int main()
{
   int rc=1;
   FILE *f=fopen("xxx","wb");
   if (f!=NULL)
   {
      size_t written = fwrite(touch,sizeof(touch),1,f);
      if (written != 1)
      {
         fprintf(stderr,"disk write issue\n");
      }
      else
      {
         rc = 0;
      }
      fclose(f);
   }
   else
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"cannot create file\n");
   }
   return rc;
}
```

Here I'm able to use `sizeof(touch)` to get the proper size because `touch` is an array, not just a pointer on data.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, no more no less :)

Answer (score -2):

```
// Open a file for writing. 
// (This will replace any existing file. Use "w+" for appending)
FILE *file = fopen("filename", "wb");

int results = fputs(array, file);
if (results == EOF) {
     // Failed to write do error code here.
}
fclose(file);
```

Comment: Better to use _binary_ mode `fopen("filename", "wb");`  `fputs(array)` assumes `array` is a string.

Comment: `fputs` will stop at the first zero.

Comment: Hint: `fwrite()`.